# Recover local corrupted file

Tags: linux-mint, lvm, disk, disk-encryption, corruption

I have a file which became corrupted on my computer and I need it back if at all possible.

I am using Linux Mint with an encrypted LVM. I have tried using `ecryptfs-recover-private` but the file is corrupt there as well.

Answer (score 0):

try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or [fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck) , Gparted check or verify part and at last [photoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

Comment: How would that help with an encrypted disk/partition?

Comment: @roaima You should obviously mount your encrypted partition first and then try using above mentioned tools.